# ?? in the modeline instead of the line number

Tags: mode-line

I have seen [posts](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3827/2592) on the topic of getting "??" in the modeline instead of the line number. However despite my best efforts I can't get rid of the problem.

I have put those settings in my config:

```
  (setq line-number-display-limit nil)
  (setq line-number-display-limit-width most-positive-fixnum)
```

I'm pretty sure they help, *sometimes* now it's OK. But at least half of the time it's not. It's funny, I made myself a [test file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22600720/no_lines.txt) and it's kind of randomly working or not...

I'm using `spacemacs` and put [my config](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/dotspacemacs) on github.

By the way, [this](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/spacemacs/packages.el#L2320) is the relevant code in spacemacs if that helps...

Comment: I've set it to a lower value meanwhile which ironically seems to work better than the previous approach of using the highest possible one.

Comment: indeed by setting it at 250.000 now my test file works every time! if you make an answer, i'll award you the answer. I hope it won't come back though...

Comment: I think I'll try figuring out why that works first and then answer, no matter the outcome.

Comment: I'm ok with closing that question and putting all the info in the other question (which I reference in my question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did replace the value of `line-number-display-limit-width` with something substantially smaller eventually and that fixed the issue for me.  Judging by the code in `xdisp.c` Emacs is using a heuristics that involves multiplying `line-number-display-limit-width` with the window height times two plus thirty.  Doing that on `most-positive-fixnum` will overflow into a negative number and probably makes the heuristics fail.

Assuming the worst case with a 32bit system (where `most-positive-fixnum` is `2^29-1`) and with 85 lines of text, a safe value should be `(2^29-1)/(2*85+30) = 2684354` or lower.  So, try the following instead (and keep `line-number-display-limit` as is):

```
(setq line-number-display-limit-width 2000000)
```