# Why in shell mode not show row/column number in mode line?

Tags: shell, mode-line

Emacs 26.1
I use smart mode line https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line.
Here result:

[image]

As you can see in *scratch* buffer show row/column numbers. But in shell mode not. Why?
How I can fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What piece of code in Emacs makes \`line-number-mode\` print "??" as line number in buffers with long lines?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3824/what-piece-of-code-in-emacs-makes-line-number-mode-print-as-line-number-i)