# How can I delete specified lines?

Tags: deletion

I want to delete lines with number `03,08,13,18,...., 3+5n.`

How can I do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use `forward-line` and `line-number-at-pos` and `delete-region` -- with `line-beginning-position` and `line-end-position`.

Comment: I wanted to add a comment of a faster method for calculating the line number, which has certain limitations discussed in the comments of the questions/answers of the thread in the following link relating to using `(format-mode-line "%l")`:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3822/2287  What spawned that particular thread, was the need to do 50 calculations of line numbers per command loop, so I needed something faster.

Answer (score 8):

The Swiss army knife of Emacs is called *keyboard macros*. See the [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros#keyboard_macro) and the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html).

Enter the macro mode, perform the commands of the macro (note: the commands are not only recorded, they are also executed).

Steps:

- Save your file for backup!
- Go to line 3 of your file
- Enter macro recording mode : `C-x (`
- Delete this line : `M-x kill-whole-line`
- Go down 4 times : <kbd>down ↓</kbd> <kbd>down ↓</kbd> <kbd>down ↓</kbd> <kbd>down ↓</kbd>
- Close the macro : `C-x )`

In case of any error during this process, you have to cancel the macro recording (`C-g`), *undo* until the file is back to the original state (or reload), then create the macro again.

You should now be on line 8.

To repeat the sequence of commands, do `C-x e`. If you don't do anything else and want to repeat again the macro execution, just enter `e`, after `C-x e` was executed.

To repeat the macro 3 times, do `C-u 3 C-x e`, etc. To repeat the macro until the end of the file is reached (or more generally until an error occurs), do `C-u 0 C-x e`.

Answer (score 3):

The following function (briefly tested) will allow you to delete lines with a starting value and a step value:

```
(defun delete-some-lines (&optional start step)
  "Delete lines starting with START at STEP intervals."
  (interactive)
  (let ((lines (list (or start
                         (string-to-number (read-string "Starting line: ")))))
        (step  (or step (string-to-number (read-string "Skipping: "))))
        (last  (line-number-at-pos (point-max))))
    (while (<= (+ step (car lines)) last)
      (push (+ step (car lines)) lines))
    (save-excursion
      (cl-dolist (line lines)
        (goto-line line)
        (delete-region (point-at-bol)
                       (min (1+ (point-at-eol)) (point-max)))))))
```

Note that it doesn't do any error checking.

Answer (score 1):

If the user wishes to also delete the `\n` at the end of the line, then just change `(line-end-position)` to `(1+ (line-end-position))`.

```lisp
(defun delete-line-number (line)
"Doc-string."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-line line)
    (delete-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```el
(defun delete-3+5n-lines ()
  "Delete the 3+5n linum lines in current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((lines (split-string (buffer-string) "\n"))
         (max-linum (length lines))
         (3+5n-linums
          (cl-loop for x from 0
                   for y = (+ 3 (* 5 x))
                   until (> y max-linum)
                   collect y)))
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert
     (mapconcat
      #'identity
      (cl-loop for x from 1 to max-linum
               unless (memq x 3+5n-linums)
               collect (elt lines (1- x)))
      "\n"))))
```

Comment: `erase-buffer` -- Are you serious?  This approach looks like a machete instead of a scalpel!  What if there are overlays?  What if there are text properties?  What if . . .  My comments underneath the question of the original poster basically give the ingredients of what *should be* a valid answer . . .

Comment: Yes, since op wants to modify a buffer/file, and also for simplicity (deleting some specific lines in place is difficult). I'm not sure if overlay or test properties make difference. Besides, personally I would like to use bash+sed, not elisp.