# hide-show with linum

Tags: performance, linum-mode, hideshow

When working on huge files, it seems that when `hide-show` collapses a large multi-line block, `linum` still creates hidden overlays for every line in the hidden block leading to unresponsive emacs. Is there a way to fix `linum`?

To reproduce: Create a new file, enable `c-mode`, `hs-minor-mode` and `linum-mode`,
create a huge block by typing: `{ C-u 10000 RET }`
then execute `hs-hide-all` and watch Emacs become unresponsive.

Comment: Try the `nlinum` package from GNU ELPA. Does that work better for you?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to fix `linum.el`, but nobody *really* cares (except me).  For starters, it can be restricted to only the visible window -- requiring a modification of the C source code to be efficient so that `window-start` and `window-end` values are always accurate [ https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22404 ].  Second, the `line-number-at-pos` can be replaced with `(format-mode-line "%l")` [with some exceptions http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3821/a-faster-method-to-obtain-line-number-at-pos-in-large-buffers ].  Third, it can be written to exclude invisible lines.

Comment: Yes! nlinum seems to do the trick.