# speed up sml-modeline, is this possible?

Tags: mode-line, package-development, optimization

I really like the package [sml-modeline](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.de/2010/03/showing-buffer-position-in-mode-line.html) (it is available on melpa): https://melpa.org/#/sml-modeline With it I replaced my vertical scrollbars.

But when opening large text files like this [Raspbian-Package-List (warning: 38MB download)](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-armhf/Packages) then Emacs gets realy slow. Disabling `sml-modeline-mode` instantly speeds up emacs.

So I had a look at [sml-modelines source code](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/sml-modeline.el). In function `sml-modeline-create` there is  a call to `widen` and `point-max`, which I suspect to make `sml-modeline-mode` so slow *(*1*)*.

**If *(*1*)* is the case, is it possible to store those values in between calls of `sml-modeline-create` to speed things up, and how do it?** I think those values need to be stored for every single buffer, or every time a call to switch-to-buffer is done.

**If *(*1*)* is not the case, what operations make `sml-modeline-mode` so slow and how to speed this up?**

This Package did not get an update since January 2012, so maybe it is already abandoned. :-(

Comment: The slow-down is due to `line-number-at-pos` that is called in a few places.  For a fix/workaround, see this related thread entitled "**A faster method to obtain `line-number-at-pos` in large buffers**":  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3821/a-faster-method-to-obtain-line-number-at-pos-in-large-buffers  You may also wish to tell the author about this problem and workaround/fix.  Essentially, you can use `(save-excursion (goto-char ...))` with the answer by Constantine in the related thread.

Comment: @lawlist wow it is working. :) One need to replace `(setq number-max (line-number-at-pos (point-max))) (setq number-beg (line-number-at-pos wstart)) (setq number-end (line-number-at-pos wend)))` with `(save-excursion (goto-char (point-max)) (setq number-max (string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l"))) (goto-char wstart) (setq number-beg (string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l"))) (goto-char wstart) (setq number-end (string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l")))))` if you write a answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slow-down is caused by calls to `line-number-at-pos`.  As mentioned in the answer by username `Constantine` in the related thread entitled "**A faster method to obtain `line-number-at-pos` in large buffers**" https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3822/2287, `(string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l"))` can be used to expeditiously extract the line number from a buffer that is **visible**.  There are a few exceptions discussed in the answer and comments of the aforementioned thread that are certainly worth reading.

The general way to apply this approach is by using `(save-excursion (goto-char ...) (string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l")))`.  If a string instead of a raw number is desired, then just remove the `string-to-number` statement from the above snippet.

The original poster has commented underneath the question applying this approach to the specific fact pattern of `sml-modeline`; however, @lawlist has not done any testing with said library and is unable to post a specific answer in relation thereto.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the author of sml-modeline is not updating, here a step by step guide:

1.) open `sml-modeline.el` from your install directory
 (probably: `~/.emacs.d/elpa/sml-modeline-20120110.1240/sml-modeline.el`)

2.) goto line 139 of the file and replace lines

```
 (setq number-max (line-number-at-pos (point-max)))
 (setq number-beg (line-number-at-pos wstart))
 (setq number-end (line-number-at-pos wend)))
```

with:

```
(save-excursion (goto-char (point-max))
                (setq number-max (string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l")))
                (goto-char wstart)
                (setq number-beg (string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l")))
                (goto-char wstart)
                (setq number-end (string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l")))))
```

3.) save and do `M-x` `byte-compile-file`
 4.) restart emacs