# get buffer scroll position and height (aka min and max on-screen buffer locations)

Tags: buffers, window, scrolling

I'm interested in the region of a buffer that is visible on-screen.

How do you get the current scroll position of a buffer?  I.e. the line number of the topmost line in the viewable area?  (Given that I can use `window-height` to find the bottommost visible line of the buffer.)

(The `point-min` and `point-max` functions give the min and max buffer positions, but those might be offscreen.  I want to know the min and max on-screen buffer positions.)

Comment: This is actually much more complex than it seems because `window-start` and `window-end` cannot be known with a 100% degree of accuracy until the end of the **redisplay** cycle.  `line-number-at-pos` is too slow in large buffers, and `(string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l"))` has some limitations:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3821/a-faster-method-to-obtain-line-number-at-pos-in-large-buffers  For a few functions that require speed in large buffers, I have used `(save-excursion (goto-char) (string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l")))`.

Comment: A combination of the `post-command-hook` and `window-scroll-functions` hook can be used to obtain `window-start` and `window-end` in about 90% of the situations, but the latter fires several times under certain circumstances before the final values will be almost accurate.  There is an option argument for `window-end` to update the value.  Due to the present impossibility of ascertain the correct `window-start`/`window-end` values with 100% accuracy, I have been implementing my own feature requests written in C as part of the `redisplay` cycle, which of course is not the answer you seek ... :)

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for the answers and information!  It is good to know that `window-start` and `window-end` are not 100% accurate and I should consider the redisplay cycle when using them.  Can you link me to any threads on the cases where `window-start` and `window-end` don't work?  Also, `(string-to-number (format-mode-line "%l"))` appears to only give me the line number of `point`, from which I cannot tell the top visible line in the window.  However, thanks again :)

Comment: To get the line number at `window-start`, you could use `(save-excursion (goto-char (window-start (selected-window))) (format-mode-line "%l"))`.  To get a line at `window-end`, you could use `(save-excursion (goto-char (window-end (selected-window) 'force)) (format-mode-line "%l"))`.  Add `string-to-number` if so desired.  Beware of certain limitations discussed in the comments of the linked thread hereinabove.  Here is a link to a thread where I began my journey:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923371/emacs-calculating-new-window-start-end-without-redisplay

Comment: To follow my journey, you may wish to read through feature request 22404:  https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22404  And see also Eli Z.'s comment regarding bug 22637: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2016-02/msg00952.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(line-number-at-pos (window-start))
```

should do what you asked.