# How to detect the number of lines scrolled from scroll up/down?

Tags: scroll

When running `scroll-up` or `scroll-down`, it's possible emacs isn't scrolling the number of lines requested (if you hit the start/end of the buffer for eg).

Is there a convenient way to know how many lines were actually scrolled?

Comment: I am unaware of anything available to the user via Lisp.  In case you do not find anything on point to suit your needs, you may wish to consider programmatically calculating the values.  If so, then it may be helpful to quickly find the line number at position:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3821/a-faster-method-to-obtain-line-number-at-pos-in-large-buffers -- keeping in mind that it has limitations as described in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt:

```
(defvar jpk/scroll-count 0
  "Signed number of lines scrolled in the last scroll-up or scroll-down.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'jpk/scroll-count)

(defun jpk/scroll-tracking (orig &rest args)
  (let ((start (window-start))
        (error t))
    (unwind-protect
        (prog1
            (apply orig args)
          (setq error nil))
      (when error
        (setq jpk/scroll-count 0)))
    (setq jpk/scroll-count (* (signum (- (window-start) start))
                              (count-lines (window-start) start)))))

(advice-add 'scroll-up :around #'jpk/scroll-tracking)
(advice-add 'scroll-down :around #'jpk/scroll-tracking)
```

I used `count-lines` because `line-number-at-pos` can be slow.  But `count-lines` implicitly takes the absolute value, hence the `signum`.  Also I'm not sure I got the error handling exactly right.

Comment: `count-lines` suffers the same problem as `line-number-at-pos`, which also uses `count-lines`.  See the link in my comment underneath the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```el
(setq max-lines (- (window-height) next-screen-context-lines))
(if (< (lines-before) max-lines) 0 max-lines)
(if (< (lines-after) max-lines) 0 max-lines)

(defun lines-before ()
  "Report number of lines on current page, and how many are before or after point."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let
      (
        (opoint (point))
        beg
        end
        total
        before
        after)
      (forward-page)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (or (looking-at page-delimiter) (end-of-line))
      (setq end (point))
      (backward-page)
      (setq beg (point))
      (count-lines beg opoint))))

(defun lines-after ()
  "Report number of lines on current page, and how many are before or after point."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let
      (
        (opoint (point))
        beg
        end
        total
        before
        after)
      (forward-page)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (or (looking-at page-delimiter) (end-of-line))
      (setq end (point))
      (backward-page)
      (setq beg (point))
      (count-lines opoint end))))
```

I took the code from `count-lines-page` and turned it into two functions that outputs how many lines exist above and below the position at point.

Then, it's just a matter of finding out if the scroll will take place. In the above case, I'm finding out how many lines will be scrolled if I hit `scroll-down-command` or `scroll-up-command`.

Not sure if this helps. I'm a newbie in Elisp.

Answer (score 0):

I use a thing like this

```lisp
(defun jump-length-test (window _window-start-after)
  (with-selected-window window
    (unless (> 0.001 (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) buffer-display-time))) ; Don't run this function after a change of buffer.
      (let* ((bottom-line-before (line-number-at-pos (window-end)))
             (bottom-line-after (line-number-at-pos (window-end nil 'update))) ; NB: ‘window-start’ doesn't take the ‘update’ argument.
             (vertical-displacement (- bottom-line-after bottom-line-before)))
        (message "Lines scrolled: %s" (abs vertical-displacement))))))

(add-hook 'window-scroll-functions #'jump-length-test)
```

It checks if the difference between the `current-time` and the `buffer-display-time` is under 0.001 s to avoid running when you change the buffer displayed by the window (which also triggers `window-scroll-functions`), and then it compares the line number of the bottom lines before and after the jump to get its length.