# Get current point position in elisp function

Tags: init-file, buffers, point

I want to make a logger that display line number of the point.
In init.el I wrote the following function:

```
(defun logger ()
"Print logger"
    (print (concat "print(\"" (what-line) ": \")")))
```

When I call the function from an other buffer it always prints `Line 1`.
However when I do `M-x what-line` the correct line number is displayed.

What can I do to make the function printing the right line number?

[image]

Edit: I found that the issue was `C-x p`.
If I do `M-x logger` it works like expected.
Why have we two different behaviors ?

Comment: The functions `point`, `point-min`, and `point-max` operate on the _current_ buffer. (`what-line` uses `point-min`). See 
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Point.html, https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/what_002dline.html, `simple.el` and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3821/a-faster-method-to-obtain-line-number-at-pos-in-large-buffers might be interesting

Comment: Same result with `(print (number-to-string (point))))` in init.el. On the current buffer 1 is always printed. Where is this value come from ?

Comment: it will always be 1 if you don't move the point.

Comment: Each buffer has its own current point. That is, what makes nega's comment meaningful: "The functions `point`, `point-min`, and `point-max` operate on the current buffer." Note, that even that is a bit simplified, since windows for the same buffer also hold their separate values for point. If you change the selected window you also change current point. (See the doc of [`switch-to-buffer-preserve-window-point`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Switching-Buffers.html#index-switch_002dto_002dbuffer_002dpreserve_002dwindow_002dpoint)

Comment: Could you explain why you want to create this 'logger'? Of course, the current-line number is printed by default in the mode line. If you want to print the line-number of some other buffer, then you probably should use `with-current-buffer`. Also, you should not use `what-line` with `print` (what line already uses `message)`. You probably want to use `line-number-at-pos`.

Comment: It's for debug purpose and variable values monitoring.
I want to automatically insert `print(f"Line 42: {}")` and fill it with variable name `print(f"Line 42: var1 = {var1}")` to print var1 value on output.

Comment: Your function do exactly what you want it to do. Place the point in any place in any buffer ad type `M-: (logger) RET`. It will print the line number where the point is.

Comment: I think the `global-set-key` is wrong. Instead of binding `C-x p` to logger, it binds it to the result of the call to `logger`, when `global-set-key` was called. I think it should be `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x p") #'logger)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to my answer.

The first is that your code works perfectly fine for me. I pasted your function into my `*scratch*` buffer, inserted an `(interactive)` declaration, and evaluated it. Then I typed `M-x logger` and it put "print("Line 75: ")" into the echo area as expected. If I move the cursor to a different line, it reports a different line number, as expected.

The second part is that based on your comments, you are writing a debug macro and you want to print the line number from the source code where the macro was invoked. Unfortunately I must disappoint you; Emacs does not keep track of that information. It does keep track of the line numbers when it encounters a `defun` or `defvar`, but not for arbitrary expressions. Implementing this feature will require you to extend the Emacs Lisp interpreter and compiler, which unfortunately is not an easy task.